# C# Python Межпроцессорное взаимодействие

Tags: python, c#, .net

Имеется нейронная сеть распознавания изображений реализованная на Python. Стоит задача передачи изображения в формате BMP от приложения на C# в скрипт.

```cs
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
processStartInfo.Arguments = scriptPath;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();

StreamWriter inputStream = process.StandardInput;
StreamReader outputStream = process.StandardOutput;

inputStream.AutoFlush = true;
inputStream.BaseStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
//inputStream.Close();

while (true) {
    char[] buffer = new char[100];
    int readed = outputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (readed == 0) break;
    Console.WriteLine("Readed: " + string.Join("", buffer.Take(readed)));
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Скрипт:

```py
import sys
import numpy

buff = sys.stdin.buffer.read(100)
img = numpy.frombuffer(buff, dtype='uint8')
sys.stdout.write(str(img))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Странность в том, что запись в стандартный поток ввода Python происходит только в момент когда он закрывается (строчка закомментирована для демонстрации ошибки). Предполагается что нейронной сети последовательно будут отправляться изображения на распознавание через стандартный поток ввода и ответ будет читаться из стандартного потока вывода. Как можно исправить данное поведение либо реализовать межпроцессорное взаимодействие иным образом?

Python 3.11.2

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145767/discussion-on-question-by-d-stark-c-python--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.